# Does the 'Civil War: Deluxe Collection' contain all the "Civil War" books?

Tags: marvel, marvel-civil-war

Does the 'Civil War: Deluxe Collection' contain all the "Civil War" books? Or do I still need to buy more books after getting this one?
.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are talking about [this book](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/4362177-civil-war) since you initially said Marvel's Civil War graphic novel. If that is the book you are referencing, then it contains all issues, #1-7, of the [Marvel Civil War Comic Event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_War_(comics)).  There are however various comics that tie into the story line and a sequel series, [Marvel Civil War II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_War_II).

All that being said, I own a copy of the book I linked and it seemed to me to be a complete story in itself.